# How to avoid re-running an actor in Akka?

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, akka

I am new to Akka. For a project I am using Play framework 2 in and I need to run a scheduled job.
For this I am using an use

```
Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES),
                                   Duration.create(3, TimeUnit.HOURS),
                                   dailyImportActor,
                                   "import",
                                   Akka.system().dispatcher(),
                                   null);
```

The job that the actor is doing is a long running job and can take from 1-4 hours. My question is that. what will happen if the actor is still busy with doing its job and time for the next time come? Does the actor gets recreated? does it block and queue somewhere and runs after?
Thanks!

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Looks like he's using Java, he still needs parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just sending a message to the actor every 3 hours. If the actor is "busy", the messages will be queued in his inbox. To avoid queueing messages, you should use the other approach described [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/howto.html) or a variant:

```
class ScheduleInReceive extends Actor {
  import context._

  override def preStart() =
    system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(500 millis, self, "tick")

  // override postRestart so we don't call preStart and schedule a new message
  override def postRestart(reason: Throwable) = {}

  def receive = {
    case "tick" =>
      // send another periodic tick after the specified delay
      system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(1000 millis, self, "tick")
      // do something useful here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The message would be queued, if the actor is still busy. If you want to start parallel work then, you could add another actor to create the actual workers.

Comment: Why not future/parrallel collections?